# Visual Studio C++ 2005/2010 with boost 1.50: warning C4267

Tags: c++, boost, warnings

I'm unable to prevent this warning..

```
...\boost\asio\impl\io_service.ipp(46) : warning C4267: 'argument' : conversion from 'size_t' to 'std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::_Ty', possible loss of data
```

Perhaps you got

1. An explanation for this
2. The solution to prevent the throwing :-)

kindly,

alex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> an explanation for this

Suspect this is a 64-bit build and `size_t` will be 64-bit and `unsigned int` will be 32-bit:

```
std::cout << sizeof(unsigned int) << "\n"; // Output '4' on both x86 and x64
std::cout << sizeof(size_t)       << "\n"; // Output '4' on x86
                                           // Output '8' on x64
```

> the solution to prevent the throwing

Add the compiler flag `/Wd4267` to disable this warning. However, that would disable the warning for all sources in your project which you may dislike. An alternative is to use [`#pragma warning`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2c8f766e%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

```
#pragma warning(disable: 4267)
#include <boost-header-files>
#pragma warning(default: 4267)
```

Comment: ok.. the explanation is valid to my thoughts.. the pragma although.. BUT it´s not solving the problem.. even if i add the #pragma the warning get still thrown.. tried it already

Comment: You may need to wrap the function in `#pragma` where the boost classes are used.

Comment: @AlexTape - that should be 4267, not 4276

Comment: I am getting the same warning. I am using VS2005, Boost-1.63.0 and I am doing a **32-bit** build.

Comment: This should be `/wd4267` (with small `w`), not `/Wd4267`.